# Is there any free portable (meaning <100mb ) IDE for C++ windows developers with compiler capable of codehinting and tested working with Win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, api, compiler-construction, ide

What I need is a small sized IDE+compiler for creating C++ applications that will interact with win32APIs... And It'd be grat for it to be capable of analizing headers I give it for code completion and connecting DLL's (not .Net DLLs but If it'd be capable ofcompiling C++ .NET projects I would just be super-duper glad) to project should be eazy. So I know my requirements are hard. For example for C# I found [SharpDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop) but it does not provide C++ capabileties... so Any Ideas, please

Comment: Hmmm... I just bought a 10GB thumb drive for $50...

Comment: I just bought a QNAP NAS w/8 TB storage for 1500. :)

Comment: Pah!  I got a spellchecker in my browser for 8MB.

Comment: I would suggest reading  the 'Programming Windows' by Charles Petzold. If you truely understand this book you will quickly realise programming Windows (the WIN32 API) is fairly simple and requires nothing but a good compiler, linker and text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is another one to consider. The binaries for the IDE + the Mingw compiler are only 73 MB compressed. Code::Blocks *should* be able to do all or most of what you want, though I'm pretty sure it can't do any C++/CLI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse IDE for C++ developers comes in at 88MB
[direct download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR1/eclipse-cpp-helios-SR1-win32.zip)
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr1

The IDE installed is more than 100mb, but it still has a very small footprint after installation...

Comment: It does everything you would expect a C++ IDE to do. The only place I have found it lacking in the past is when debugging, it's just a bit different that what you might expect from Visual Studio IDE. It's not necessarily worse, I just didn't like it as much.

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html) is another possible option.

and it has an even smaller footprint than Eclipse IDE